# Including taxonomy archive links into WordPress editor link search

Tags: search, taxonomy

I'm looking for a way to include the taxonomy archive links in the search results when Inserting/Editing a link from inside the WordPress post Editor. Specifically through the "Insert/edit link" search box. So that I can have an easy and quick way to add a link directly to a taxonomy archive page from the text inside the article as I'm editing/typing it.

Of course I would prefer to do this using only direct code and not having to install a separate plugin.